# Import configuration and set variables. Also replace forward slash to backslash

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a configuration file that has several variable names with a value.

E.g. `variable=value`

A few of these variables have path values like `C:/folder1`. Other variables have values which are a filename like `file1.txt`.

Now the path values have forward slashes because I use this same configuration file for shell scripts. Therefore, I have to convert the forwardslashes into backslashes for this batch script.

When I run the command below it imports all the config variables and their values into my batch file, whilst also converting the slashes:

```
for /f "delims== tokens=1*" %%A in (config\config.sh) do (set "%%A=%%~fB")
```

While this works great, the non path values are being affected. So for example, the variables with filenames in get a path pre-fixed to it.
So instead of having `file1=file1.txt`, it becomes `file1=C:\folder1\file1.txt`

Is there a way I can convert the slashes for the variables that have paths in, whilst importing the other variables with filenames in etc, without any issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /f "delims== tokens=1*" %%A in (q44312204.txt) do set "%%A=%%B"& CALL SET "%%A=%%%%A:/=\%%"
```

I used a file named `q44312204.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Having set the variable `%%A` to a value, the `call` sets `%%A` to `%% %%A:/=\ %%` which, for `%%A`=file1 and `%%B`=C:/folder1/file1.txt sets `file1`=`C:/folder1/file1.txt` then calls `set "file1 = %% file1:/=\ %%"` which executes `set "file1 = % file1:/=\ %"` since `%%` is an escaped-`%` (note that in this paragraph, I've inserted spaces in the command-being-executed for emphasis)

Note that the `~f` which was performing the conversion but prefixing the current-directory has been removed.

Comment: This did exactly what I asked for. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do something like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1* Delims==" %%A In ("config\config.sh") Do (Set "_=%%B"
    Set "%%A=!_:/=\!")
```

I would probably suggest though placing something at the beginning `$%%A` so that you can easily access all of your variables at once thus `Set $`.